# images in <div data-src= are not showing in MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

I'm using asp.net with mvc-4 in Microsoft visual studio 2012.
And the page have an image slider
The Index.cshtml is the following :

```
<div class="camera-wrapper">
<div id="camera" class="camera-wrap">

    <div data-src="~/Images/index_slide01.jpg">
        <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
            <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Solutions that you need!</h2>
            <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-src="~/images/index_slide02.jpg">
        <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
            <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit!</h2>
            <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-src="~/images/index_slide03.jpg">
        <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
            <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur!</h2>
            <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see , the images in  are not showing when running the app, whereas using

```
<img src="images/logo.png"> is working normally .
```

How to let the images show in

```
 <div data-src >
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would images from a `data-*` attribute show up? You need some corresponding Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: in the static html page they are showing up , but when used in mvc they aren't .
and there is some corresponding javascript/jQuery , its an image slider .

Comment: Then are you missing a reference to the image slider javascript? Or do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: no I copied the code from  the static html page and configured the paths of the css/js files and everything works fine , even the images are appearing normally if I use <img src=".." > , but the data-src thing is not showing them

Answer (score 1):

The '~' sign not work without `@Url.Content`. Please change your code as below.

```
<div class="camera-wrapper">
<div id="camera" class="camera-wrap">

    <div data-src="@Url.Content("~/Images/index_slide01.jpg")">
        <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
            <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Solutions that you need!</h2>
            <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-src="@Url.Content("~/images/index_slide02.jpg")">
        <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
            <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit!</h2>
            <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-src="@Url.Content("~/images/index_slide03.jpg")">
        <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
            <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur!</h2>
            <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Its @url.content in mvc-4 ,
And I have tried it before and it didn't work

Comment: Worked for me. Great answer